# python quiz with subject options

Tags: python

```
 print("plese choose a topic of your liking")
History = ('History')
Music = ('Music')
Computer_science = ('Computer science')
print (History, Music, Computer_science)


History = print("when did the Reichstag fires begin?")
one = ("1) 1937")
two = ("2) 1933")
three = ("3) 1935")
print (one, two, three)
guess = int(input())
if guess == 2: #this makes it so any option appart from 2 is outputed as 'wrong'
    print ("well done")
else:
    print("wrong")
```

I have created the first part of my python quiz, It took me a while to figure out, I have also created a list that contains 3 different subjects, Do any of you know how to assign a button to each element within my subject list? If this does not make any sense, please let me know (I'm new to this site)

Comment: what do you mean button? this be python there is no interface if you don't make it

Comment: e.g. if you pres 1 or 2 or 3 it opens the desired quiz subject

Comment: so you want to know how to make a simple menu interface... mkay

Comment: Yep, that's the long and short of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get this sort of behaviour you can make an input before everything else which determines what subject you choose based on user input. so something REAL simple like:

```
subject = int(input("Please choose what subject you would like 
(number):\n[1]History\n[2]Maths\n[3]Geography\n"))

if subject == 1:
    print("You have chosen History")
elif subject == 2:
    print("You have chosen Maths")
elif subject == 3:
    print("You have chosen Geography")
else:
    print("that is not an available option")
```

This is probably the simplest it can get with menus... If you type 1 and press enter you get history and so on. i dont know how your program works but do what fits in.

There are probably better ways too this is just what I remember doing back in the day. Very simple stuff

Comment: thanks for the help, I appreciate it

Comment: just try getting some research done on python input (https://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html)

Comment: Ok. Ill be sure to check that out